# Unity Facebook SDK app request not working with mobile app

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am having a problem with sending request though the Facebook mobile app.
When the FB mobile app is not install, the CUI interface came up and request can send properly.
However, when the app is install, there are pop up boxes asking for permission for request, but nothing happen after that. This only happened on Android devices. It works fine on iPhone 5.
Just wonder is this a bug that created by the mobile app, or is there anyway round this ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the setting openssl is wrong.I had same problem like you.When facebook app is install,when facebook sdk call facebook API,facebook app will call our app,but Android must be set keyhash,when keyhash is wrong,it can't work.IOS do not need keyhash.So openssl must be base64.Of course,you have to copy the settings to facebook website.I have solved it like this.Hope it can help you.

Comment: I tried to add the hash key in, but it still doesn't work. Just wonder if it is possible to have multiple hash keys in the field ? Because I now have got the key from Unity editor facebook panel and one generate from command promote which are difference, I have put both in.

Comment: Maybe you could debug keyhash.Try this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/609810/using-facebook-api-with-android-says-login-is-canc.html